# Can a price set item be marked "Partially Deductible"?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, price-sets, taxes

Is there a way to add an item and indicate that an item's cost is partly deductible?  For instance, a $500 ticket to a gala dinner that has a $400 deductible component.

I see where to mark financial types as tax-deductible - and I see that there's a field called `non_deductible_amount` in the `civicrm_contribution` table.  However, I'm not clear how to populate that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's just a manually-set field.  It certainly predates the accounting improvements, and I think it predates price sets.

The problem is that it's not always a reasonable assumption that the bulk of a contribution is deductible.  You might have a organization with a 501(c)3 arm and a 501(c)4 arm.  The dinner is $500 per couple, toward the c3, with $100 non-deductible because it's the value of the dinner itself.  Then, they ask for a $250 contribution to the c4 on the form as well.  The result is that really only $400 of the $750 is deductible, but the `non_deductible_amount` is $100.

Really, this needs to be at the line-item level or dropped entirely.

I tend to avoid the field and encourage folks to just say in the receipt text that they received $100 worth of goods/services in return for the gift.  The donor can do the math, and it's not too important for the organization to track that at the contribution level.